# vscode run python files in a subdirectory with imports from other subdirectory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path

I looked up a lot of threads but none solved my issue

I have the following dir in my project

```
my_proj

    folder_one
          __init__.py
          file_one.py

    folder_two
          __init__.py
          file_two.py

    __init__.py
    main.py
```

I am trying to import from `file_two.py` the `FileTwo` class:

file_one.py:

```
from folder_two.file_two import FileTwo
```

But i get the following error when I try to run the `file_one.py` file:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder_two'
```

I tried the following:

- Adding `PYTHONPATH` to .env file
- Adding `"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"` to settings.json
- Adding `"terminal.integrated.env.osx"` to settings.json
- Adding `"python.analysis.extraPaths"` to settings.json
- Adding `"python.autoComplete.extraPaths"` to settings.json
- Adding `__init__.py` to every folder exists in my project

When I print the `sys.path` from `file_one.py` I get the path: `/my_proj/folder_one` instead of `/my_proj`

How can I add the `/my_proj` root directory of my project to sys.path (not permanently) so I could run any python file in my project and still access all files?

Answer (score 2):

The import line be modified as `from folder_two.file_two import FileTwo`, notice that `.py` is removed.

Then in the root directory, `python main.py` should work.

Also, if file_one.py has a main function, then you can launch with
`python -m folder_one.file_one`. Noticed that `.py` is not used.

Be aware to test the problems in terminal first. There are more tricky parts in IDEs, e.g. `Pycharm`, since they might automatically change working directories or do something else that is not so obvious.

Comment: I edited the post. the `.py` is not the problem. I am trying to run the `file_one.py` from vscode and not `main.py`

Comment: Should run `python -m folder_one.file_one` in the root folder of your project.

Answer (score 1):

How do you modified the `"terminal.integrated.env.osx"`? Like this?

```
  "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder};",
  },
```

And what you have added in the `.env` file? Like this(just an example, an absolute path)?

```
PYTHONPATH=c:\\Work\\python3.10
```

> The PYTHONPATH environment variable specifies additional locations
> where the Python interpreter should look for modules. In VS Code,
> PYTHONPATH can be set through the terminal settings
> (terminal.integrated.env.*) and/or within an .env file.
>
> When the terminal settings are used, PYTHONPATH affects any tools that
> are run within the terminal by a user, as well as any action the
> extension performs for a user that is routed through the terminal such
> as debugging. However, in this case when the extension is performing
> an action that isn't routed through the terminal, such as the use of a
> linter or formatter, then this setting will not have an effect on
> module look-up.
>
> When PYTHONPATH is set using an .env file, it will affect anything the
> extension does on your behalf and actions performed by the debugger,
> but it will not affect tools run in the terminal.
>
> If needed, you can set PYTHONPATH using both methods.

You can refer to the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable).